# Screen: continuously record the buffer values and save onto a file

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssh, gnu-screen

I am asking using the `screen` command in Ubuntu. I know there is a command that use `hardcopy` which basically save the buffer onto the file. But how do I continously ask `screen` to write the output onto a file for me?

If I do the following: `python my_program > recorder_this.txt`, it won't print the `stdout` and I can't see the print result. I tried the other method and I am currently running it on AWS, it seems to me that it will cause the machine to freeze. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can record the screen output with the -L option. screen will then create a file called `screenlog.0` in the directory where you ran screen (on Ubuntu you will be able to specify the filename if you want).

```
screen -L
```

Another solution is to pipe to `tee`. It will save the output to a file and also print it.

Example

```
echo "Hello" | tee file_name
```